# How to run visio-macro on vb.net-application?

Tags: vba, vb.net, visio

I have a visio document which contains macros. I have my own vb.net application which manipulates the visio document by the COM-Interface (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio). I want to run a macro of the visio document triggered by the vb.net application.

I know that this is working with excel documents. (Excel.Application.Run() )

I don't find anything similar in Visio-API.
How can I do?

Comment: [ExecuteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.document.executeline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Vinvent G! The solution is: Document.ExecuteLine("MyMakroName")